# Sign a Partially Signed rawtransaction with bitcoinjs-lib

Tags: bitcoinjs, signrawtransaction

I was trying to figure out how to use the bitcoinjs-lib. I was thinking if I could sign a partially signed raw transaction in bitcoijs-lib.

For example - If I have a hex String whose input1 is unsigned but rest of the inputs are all signed, can i Sign this raw transaction using bitcoinjs-lib?

Comment: Sure, see https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1011. Give it a try and post your code if you need help.

Comment: @JBaczuk Oh by partially signed I meant, Given a hex raw transaction which has been partially signed by one party, i.e one party signs over its inputs and then sends the partially signed raw transaction, can the other party now take the hex raw transaction, and then sign over the remaining inputs?

Comment: @ShubhamSaxena they can as long as they have the required key to do so.